# Different DB and front end for Meteor

Tags: meteor

Lets say I want to use a different DB than Mongo in Meteor's back-end and also want to use a visualization lib like D3.js on the front-end. 
Is that possible at the moment?
How complex would it be to add it by myself if not?
Thanks

Comment: You can use pretty much _any_ frontend stuff you want (hell, you can use Flash or Silverlight [shudder]) along with Meteor;  As far as the backend, I have no idea, I've been trying to find out myself which is what brought me to your question.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/mongo-livedata the documentation indicates that this would be the module to start with if you wanted to replace the database functionality.

> You can substitute another database for MongoDB by providing a
>   server-side database driver and/or a client-side cache that implements
>   an alternative API. The mongo-livedata is a good starting point for
>   such a project.

-- http://docs.meteor.com/#data

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this project: https://github.com/austinrivas/meteor-postgresql. If you really need to use a database other than mongo meteor may not be the right choice unless you are experimenting. You can always aggregate data from another db to mongo which might make life easier.

I've been using D3 with meteor in the form of angularjs directives and binding the data to drive the visualizations to $scope. DDP makes keeping the data current in the d3 visualizations super convenient.