# display data from another database in meteor

Tags: meteor

I would like to use meteor to display data to a user. I have this data in an external (jDBC accesible) database. I would like to query the database for the relevant record and display this with meteor. Are there any examples on how to accomplish this or am I completely think in a wrong direction ?

Regards,
Marco

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111128/different-db-and-front-end-for-meteor offers a start on how to implement different DB backnds.

Answer (score 0):

Right now meteor only has the capability to connect to a mongodb backend. Conceptually, there is no reason it couldn't connect to any other DB, but as of this moment it has not yet been implemented.